# Check if URL param is in list of allowed params and route accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my `app.js`, I have a list of Routes:-

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/:locale'>
      <Header />
      <Container />
      <Footer />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/notfound' component={NotFound} />
    <Redirect to='/notfound' />
  </Switch>
```

I have a URL like `www.mydomainname.com/us.` I want the first route to render the components only when the `:locale` matches `us` or `uk`. If the `:locale` is empty or something not equal to `us` or `uk` (like `au`), then the page should route to `/notfound`.

The problem I am currently facing is, if I enter `www.mydomainname.com/notfound` or any random stuff after `www.mydomainname.com/`, then the first route is executing. I know I can get the `:locale` using `useParams()`, but how do I check it against an array of allowed values and reroute to the `/notfound` page if the check fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route "/:locale" is a catch all route, so it will match any "/randomstring". Introduce a component `Body` which is a locale specific renderer.

```
<Switch>
<Route path='/notfound' component={NotFound} />
<Route path='/:locale'>
  <Body>
    <Header />
    <Container />
    <Footer />
  <Body>
</Route>
<Redirect from='/' to='/notfound' exact />
</Switch>
```

And Body component will be handling redirect

```
const Body = (props) => {
  const { locale } = useParams()
  if (["us", "uk"].indexOf(locale) != -1)
    return(props.children)
  else
    return(
      <Redirect to="/notfound" />
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works if `:locale` is anything other than 'us' or 'uk'. How do I show the `/notfound` page if the `:locale` is empty? Right now, if I visit my website with no extra params, then nothing is displayed.

Comment: Solved it. Added `<Redirect from='/' to='/notfound' exact />` inside `Switch`.

Answer (score 1):

The `react-router-dom@5` `Route` component's `path` prop uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) under the hood, so you can use this to more exactly match paths.  `path="/:locale(us|uk)"` will ***only*** match `"/us"` and `"/uk"` paths.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/:locale(us|uk)">
    <Header />
    <Container />
    <Footer />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/notfound" component={NotFound} />
  <Redirect to="/notfound" />
</Switch>
```

[image: Edit check-if-url-param-is-in-list-of-allowed-params-and-route-accordingly]